# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename' for Flask Uploads

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using **Flask 1.0.2** and **Flask-WTF 0.14.2** but I don't understand why filename is empty.

First I create a forms.py like this

```
images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)
docs = UploadSet('docs', ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'PDF', 'DOC', 'DOCX', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'PNG', 'JPEG'])
configure_uploads(app, (images, docs))
class EvenementForm(FlaskForm):
    titre = StringField(u'titre', validators=[DataRequired()])
    periode = StringField(u'periode', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField(u'description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    lieu = StringField(u'lieu', validators=[DataRequired()])
    image = FileField(u'image', validators=[FileAllowed(docs, u'Documents seulement. Le poids ne doit pas d&eacute;passer les 300 Ko!')])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EvenementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then my views.py look like this

```
@admin.route('/events', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def events():
     form = EvenementForm()
     if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
          evenement = Evenements(titre=form.titre.data, lieu=form.lieu.data, periode=form.periode.data, description=form.description.data)

          otherfile = form.image.data.filename

          if otherfile:
               otherfile = secure_filename(otherfile)
               date = "{:%I%M%S%f%d%m%Y}".format(datetime.now())
               otherfile = date + otherfile
               form.image.data.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'resumes/'+otherfile))
               evenement.image = otherfile
          db.session.add(evenement)
          db.session.commit()
          flash('Thanks for adding')
          return redirect(url_for('admin.events'))
     return render_template("admin/events.html", form=form)
```

and my template look like this :

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="event_id" value="0" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="speaker_name">Titre :</label>
            {{ form.titre(placeholder='Entrez le titre de l\'évenement', class='form-control', required='required') }}
            <span style="color:red">{% if form.titre.errors %}{{ form.titre.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="speaker_job">Lieu:</label>
            {{ form.lieu(placeholder='Entrez le lieu de l\'évenement', class='form-control', required='required') }}
            <span style="color:red">{% if form.lieu.errors %}{{ form.lieu.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="speaker_job">Lieu:</label>
            {{ form.periode(placeholder='Entrez la periode de l\'évenement', class='form-control', required='required') }}
            <span style="color:red">{% if form.periode.errors %}{{ form.periode.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="speaker_job">Lieu:</label>
            {{ form.description(placeholder='Entrez la description de l\'évenement', class='textarea textarea-style', required='required') }}
            <span style="color:red">{% if form.description.errors %}{{ form.description.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>     
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="speaker_picture">Image</label>
            {{ form.image(placeholder='Entrez l\'image de l\'évenement', class='form-control', required='required') }}
            <span style="color:red">{% if form.image.errors %}{{ form.image.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
        </div> 
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-bold btn-pure btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
            Annuler
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bold btn-pure btn-info float-right">
            Enregistrer
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I'm facing this error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'

how could I solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the encryption type to the form tag like this

```
<form class="col s12"method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `form.image.data.filename`, When user doesn't provide a file, there will be no `filename` cause the `form.image.data` will have `None` as  it's value

You need to check for `form.image.data` itself instead of it's `filename`

It goes like this:

```py
otherfile = form.image.data
if otherfile:
    # I see your assigning filename to this variable,
    # Next line does the same, I don't recommend it this way
    otherfile = otherfile.filename
    # Do other stuff
```

There is an example usage on the WTForms documentation

Also you can use [`FileRequired`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=filerequired#flask_wtf.file.FileRequired) validator on your Form's Class definition to make sure there is always a file, otherwise the data won't be valid

```
image = FileField(u'image', validators=[FileAllowed(docs, u'Documents seulement. Le poids ne doit pas d&eacute;passer les 300 Ko!'), FileRequired()])
```